# chrony not updating the server time properly in Centos 7

Tags: ntp, chrony

I am using chrony for NTP time synchronization for my Centos 7 server. some time I notice some servers time is not correct, I have to use ntpdate command to correct the time.

I have below configuration, please let me know if I am missing some configuration.

```
 egrep -v '#|^$' /etc/chrony.conf
server ntp minpoll 8
keyfile /etc/chrony/chrony.keys
commandkey 1
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/chrony.drift
log tracking measurements statistics
logdir /var/log/chrony
maxupdateskew 100.0
dumponexit
dumpdir /var/lib/chrony
local stratum 10
logchange 0.5
rtconutc
```

Thanks
SR

Comment: Can you use the iburst setting to help speed up the synchronization? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chrony

Comment: what does `chronyc sources` say? You might add `rtcsync` to the config to keep the rtc correct.

Comment: @TimothyPulliam added the iburst and restarted the chrony process. it appears to be working now. let me monitor some more time.